# Why the adjustments required to the rectangle created in CreateWindow call from coordinates from mouse

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have created a Windows program which works a little like the Windows Snipping Tool to capture a selected section of the screen. The way it captures a part of the screen is as follows:

1. Maximise the program Window (main window) and make 70% transparent (so user can see background to select in later stage).  File... Make Transparent menu option.

Rectangle selection stage is next.

2. WM_LBUTTONDOWN handling makes a copy of the top left x and y coordinates.
3. WM_MOUSEMOVE handling sets up a Windows RECT struct so you have top left height and width of rectangle.
4. WM_LBUTTONUP handling passes the RECT struct values to a capture function.  The capture function makes the main window totally transparent, makes some co-ordinate adjustments (more on this later), and the only way I could work out how to get the HDC of the rectangle area and hence grab the right rectangle on the screen is to create a new Window (called capture window in code) where the window size is initialised with the RECT struct values passed in.

The code works but I am concerned that I don't understand the adjustments to the rect I have to make so that the rectangle reflects what is actually selected by the user.

The section of the code where the adjustments are made:

```
// Create a Window the same size as the RECT to capture because you need a Window handle to call GetDC which is required 
// to make a bitmap of rectangle
// we have to make height of window same as rect - WS_OVERLAPPED has title bar and border - have to add on usual size of those
// currently assuming 32 is big enough to cover the title bar and border - works when tested on my w7 Angus-PC
int TitleAndBorderHeight = 32;

// We also have to make the following adjustments - why?
rect.left -= 4;
rect.top += 10;
rect.bottom += 10;

// In addition, the width of the captured window has to be extended by 8 pixels, otherwise you get a part of capture on right of bitmap which black
const char* ClassName = "CaptureWindowClass";
ATOM atom = RegisterCaptureWindowClass(ClassName, hInst);
HWND captureHwnd = CreateWindowA(ClassName, "Capture", WS_OVERLAPPED,
    rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left + 8, rect.bottom - rect.top + TitleAndBorderHeight, parentWnd, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);
```

Why do I need to make these adjustments to the rect?

Will the adjustments work in all possible scenarios of user screen setup?  And if not, how do I fix that?

The code for the program below (I didn't include the rc file or the resource.h file - I can if required).

```
// transparent-window.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>

#include "transparent-window.h"

#include <fstream> // logging point co-ords
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ofstream logg;  // global logging object

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK CaptureWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
bool save(const std::string& basename, const std::vector<char>& bitmap, const BITMAPINFOHEADER& bi);


ATOM RegisterCaptureWindowClass(const char* classname, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    WNDCLASSA wcex{};
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = CaptureWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = nullptr;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    // no background - want to see thru to screen user is selecting
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);

    wcex.lpszMenuName = "";
    wcex.lpszClassName = classname;

    return RegisterClassA(&wcex);
}


int Capture(/*const*/ RECT& rect, HWND parentWnd) {

    // added to make main window totally transparent AFTER you select area
    SetWindowLong(parentWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(parentWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(parentWnd, 0, (255 * 0) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);  // 0% of 255 selected - totally transparent
    // When bAlpha is 0, the window is completely transparent. When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque.

    // Create a Window the same size as the RECT to capture because you need a Window handle to call GetDC which is required 
    // to make a bitmap of rectangle
    // we have to make height of window same as rect - WS_OVERLAPPED has title bar and border - have to add on usual size of those
    // currently assuming 32 is big enough to cover the title bar and border - works when tested on my w7 Angus-PC
    int TitleAndBorderHeight = 32;

    // We also have to make the following adjustments - why?
    rect.left -= 4;
    rect.top += 10;
    rect.bottom += 10;

    // In addition, the width of the captured window has to be extended by 8 pixels, otherwise you get a part of capture on right of bitmap which black
    const char* ClassName = "CaptureWindowClass";
    ATOM atom = RegisterCaptureWindowClass(ClassName, hInst);
    HWND captureHwnd = CreateWindowA(ClassName, "Capture", WS_OVERLAPPED,
        rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left + 8, rect.bottom - rect.top + TitleAndBorderHeight, parentWnd, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);

    ShowWindow(captureHwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(captureHwnd);

    // Set WS_EX_LAYERED on this window - provides transparency feature
    SetWindowLong(captureHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(captureHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(captureHwnd, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);  // window to be completely transparent
    // When bAlpha is 0, the window is completely transparent. When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque.

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client area of the window.
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(captureHwnd);

    // Create a compatible DC, which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC.
    HDC hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

    if (!hdcMemDC)
    {
        logg << "CreateCompatibleDC has failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC.
    // The CreateCompatibleBitmap function creates a bitmap compatible with the device that is associated with the specified device context
    //                                         hdc,       bmap width,             bitmap height
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);

    if (!hbmScreen)
    {
        logg << "CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if (!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        0, 0,
        rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        logg << "BitBlt has failed" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }

    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP.
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi {};
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    std::vector<char> bitmap(dwBmpSize);

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap, and copies them into a buffer 
    // that's pointed to by bitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcScreen, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        bitmap.data(),
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // we now have char bitmap buffer representing the screen capture

    // Clean up.
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);

    // make same transparency as prior to capture so we can continue selecting rectangles
    SetWindowLong(parentWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(parentWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(parentWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);  // 70% of 255 selected - same as prior transparent

    return save("image1", bitmap, bi) ? 0 : 1;
}

bool save(const std::string& basename, const std::vector<char>& bitmap, const BITMAPINFOHEADER& bi) {

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    const std::string filename = basename + ".bmp";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(filename.c_str(),
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size.
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = static_cast<DWORD>(bitmap.size()) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Size of the file.
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    // bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps.
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // BM.

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)bitmap.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(bitmap.size()), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // Close the handle for the file that was created.
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return true;
}



int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    logg.open("hooked-messages.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TRANSPARENTWINDOW, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TRANSPARENTWINDOW));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}


// In windows you have to register a class of window to use, you set attributes and select a callback function
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TRANSPARENTWINDOW));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TRANSPARENTWINDOW);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static POINT pt{ -1, 0 };      // x- and y-coordinates of cursor
    static RECT rcTarget; // rect to receive filled shape


    static bool selected = false;


    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:

            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;

        case ID_FILE_SELECT:
            selected = true;
            break;

        case ID_FILE_MAKETRANSPARENT:

            // Set WS_EX_LAYERED on this window 
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

            //  handle to layered window, COLORREF value, alpha value, flag to specify id using COLORREF or alpha method 
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);  // 70% of 255 selected - good transparency
            // When bAlpha is 0, the window is completely transparent. When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque.

            // for our co-ordinates to work we need origin to be top left - so maximise screen before user selectes a rectangle
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {   // Save the coordinates of the cursor.  

        // wait for a flag to say we have started
        if (selected) {
            pt.x = (LONG)LOWORD(lParam);
            pt.y = (LONG)HIWORD(lParam);

            logg << "WM_LBUTTONDOWN x=" << pt.x << ", y=" << pt.y << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (selected && pt.x != -1) {
            // draw the target rectangle as the user drags the mouse

            // Set the mixing mode so that the pen color is the  
            // inverse of the background color. The previous  
            // rectangle can then be erased by drawing  
            // another rectangle on top of it.  
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            SetROP2(hdc, R2_NOTXORPEN);

            // If a previous target rectangle exists, erase  
            // it by drawing another rectangle on top.  
            if (!IsRectEmpty(&rcTarget))
            {
                Rectangle(hdc, rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top,
                    rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom);
            }

            // set target rectangle left and top to be x and y stored on WM_LBUTTONDOWN and and right and bottom
            // to be last x and y position on mousemove
            SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, pt.y, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));

            // Draw the new target rectangle.  
            Rectangle(hdc, rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top,
                rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        if (!selected)
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);


        selected = false;
        logg << "WM_LBUTTONUP x=" << pt.x << ", y=" << pt.y << std::endl;
        logg << "rcTarget left=" << rcTarget.left << ", top=" << rcTarget.top << ", right=" << rcTarget.right << ", bottom=" << rcTarget.bottom << std::endl;

        // rcTarget contains the rectangle we want to make into a bitmap
        int ret = Capture(rcTarget, hWnd);
        logg << "Capture returned " << ret << std::endl;
        logg << "screen captured to : " << "image1" << ".bmp\n";

        // reset so that user may select a subsequent rectangle to capture
        pt.x = -1;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rcTarget, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        rcTarget.right = 0;
        rcTarget.left = 0;
        rcTarget.bottom = 0;
        rcTarget.top = 0;
    }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK CaptureWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: `const std::string& basename, const std::vector<char>& bitmap` ==> This seems to be C++, why did you tag it as C?

Comment: Are you allowing for the client area that is captured being smaller than the size of the window you create? You can use `AdjustWindowRect()` to obtain the window size you need to create to obtain a given client area.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added a call to AdjustWindowRect(&adjusted, WS_VISIBLE, false) which returned TRUE but did NOT change the the rect - adjusted.

Comment: You should pass the same `style` to `AdjustWindowRect()` that you pass to `CreateWindow()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes I am doing that - changed to use WS_VISIBLE style only

Comment: What does it capture to call `BitBlt` with the source device context `captureHwnd`? Why don't you [convert (map) a set of points from a coordinate space relative to your window to a coordinate space relative to `HWND_DESKTOP` window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints)?